# How can I print column sections from SQL to Java to CSV?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, io

I have set up a MySQL database, my connection works, and I've somewhat got a handle on how to retrieve data from the database using ResultSet.  The issue I'm currently having is that the assignment calls for certain columns from a few different tables to be printed in CSV format along with replacing some values that meet certain conditions; i.e., if the cost of a plane ticket for a particular flight is under a certain price, replace the cost with "LOW!" in that part of the CSV file.  Here's what I've got:

```
public void generate() throws IOException, SQLException{

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("datamine.csv");
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fw);
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();

    out.println("Airline,FlightNumber,Source,Destination,DayOfWeek,Seats,Daysbefore,Price");

    //ResultStatements here

    out.flush();
    out.close();
    fw.close();

}
```

I know how to query the DB, and I think I can figure out how to union the columns from tables that I need, but that will just print everything in the column.  Is there a way to iterate through the columns, evaluate the value for conditionals, and then append it to the output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `while` loop, and an `if` test.

```
while (rs.next()) {

    String airline = rs.getString(1);
    ...
    BigDecimal price = rs.getBigDecimal(8);
    if (price.compareTo(limit) < 0) {
        csvFile.print("LOW!");
    }
    else {
        csvFile.print(price);
    }
}
```